# Updating remote cron via ssh

Tags: bash, ssh, cron

I need to add/remove cron jobs on multiple machines. I have the below that will add a single cron via a varible but i need the varible to add multiple i.e

CRON1=add cron && add second cron && add third cron.

I have tried various expressions but always get and error when executing the second command.

```
#!/bin/bash
USERNAME=user
HOSTS="1.2.3.4 4.3.2.1"

CRON1='(crontab -l 2>/dev/null; echo "*/5 * * * * /path/to/job") | crontab -'

for HOSTNAME in ${HOSTS} ; do
ssh -l ${USERNAME} ${HOSTNAME} << EOF

$CRON1

EOF
done
```

Comment: I would generate a tmp file with all the entries you need before the `for` loop, and then you can redirect the whole file with just `crontab << tmpfile` (I think, test carefully!). Good luck.

Comment: If you are using Bash 3+ you can do `crontab <<<string`

Answer (score 0):

Storing multiple values screams "arrays". Use arrays to store the cron jobs. Then what you can do is switch the heredoc to a pipeline that generates the requisite `echo` commands dynamically.

```
#!/bin/bash

username=user
hostnames=(1.2.3.4 4.3.2.1)
jobs=(
    '*/5 * * * * /path/to/job1'
    '*/5 * * * * /path/to/job2'
    '*/5 * * * * /path/to/job3'
)

for hostname in "${hostnames[@]}"; do
    {
        printf '{\n'
        printf 'crontab -l 2>/dev/null\n'
        for job in "${jobs[@}}"; do printf 'echo %q\n' "$job"; done
        printf '} | crontab -'
    } | ssh -l "$username" "$hostname"
done
```

Other suggestions:

- All caps variable names are reserved for the shell. It's best to avoid them for your own.
- Use singular and plural variable names in pairs. A `$hostname` is one element of the `$hostnames` array.

Comment: I get cron3.sh: line 15: ${jobs[@}}: bad substitution and -bash: line 3: syntax error: unexpected end of file